How to read a JSON file using StreamReader in C# and skip invalid nodes
I am trying to read and process a large JSON file in C# using StreamReader and JsonTextReader. My goal is to read the JSON file node by node, and if any node contains invalid data (e.g., malformed JSON or missing fields), I want to skip that node and continue processing the rest of the file.
Here’s an example of the JSON file structure I am working with:
[
  {
    "id": "a5db927f-62b3-4b30-b520-83cff902c3ef",
    "type": "message"
    "parent": null,
    "participant": "mauraans",
    "body": "We've moved the meeting out. Apologies for the last minute changes. Appears daylight savings time has caused challenges with time zones.",
    "conversation": "D04QU11BTJN",
    "importance": "normal",
    "timestamp": "1680541760.235769",
    "lastmodifiedtime": null,
    "deleted": false
  },
  {
    "id": "6db0169c-d8d9-4d27-8fa9-b60b9f163b87",
    "type": "message",
    "parent": null,
    "participant": "mauraans",
    "body": "What time did you have on your calendar and we'll go with that?",
    "conversation": "D04QU11BTJN",
    "importance": "normal",
    "timestamp": "1680539518.455199",
    "lastmodifiedtime": null,
    "deleted": false
  }
]

In the example above, the first node has a missing comma after "type": "message", making it invalid JSON. I need to handle such cases gracefully by skipping the invalid node and moving to the next one without stopping the entire process.
Here is the code I have tried:
using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
  using(BufferedStream bufferedStream = new BufferedStream(fs, 5000)) {
    using(StreamReader r = new StreamReader(bufferedStream))
    using(JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(r)) {
      JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();

      while (reader.Read()) {
        try {
          if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject) {
            var node = serializer.Deserialize < dynamic > (reader);
            Console.WriteLine(node.id);
            nodeCount++;
          }
        } catch (JsonReaderException ex) {
          reader.Skip();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


"if any node contains invalid data (e.g., malformed JSON or missing fields), I want to skip that node and continue processing the rest of the file." missing fields would be covered by json schema, probably. But malformed json? How would you know where to continue? I'd also recommend to not encourage presenting broken input and then expect it to "just work". That's a bottomless pit, really.

As a "compromise" consider json-lines. Then one malformed entry would be easier to skip.

What system is generating such malformed JSON and wwhy aren't you focussing on fixing that instead?

This is a foolish exercise.  In the instant that one of the properties has an object as a value, and starts with "{", your whole approach falls apart.  Put your energy into addressing the source data.  JSON is a standards-based data interchange format.  It's called "standards-based" for a reason.
